# Can't get ios::beg to go back to the beginning of the file

Tags: c++, text, file-io

It always seems to be the things that should be no problem that cause problems for me. I don't get it. :/

So I'm trying to make sure that I understand how to manipulate text files. I've got two files, "infile.txt" and "outfile.txt". "infile.txt" has six numbers in it and nothing else. Here is the code I used to manipulate the files.

```
#include<fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::fstream;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

int main()
{
ifstream inStream;
ofstream outStream;//create streams

inStream.open("infile.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
outStream.open("outfile.txt");//attach files

int first, second, third;
inStream >> first >> second >> third;
outStream << "The sum of the first 3 nums is " << (first+second+third) << endl;
//make two operations on the 6 numbers
inStream >> first >> second >> third;
outStream << "The sum of the second 3 nums is " << (first+second+third) << endl;

inStream.seekg(0); //4 different ways to force the program to go back to the beginning of the file
//2. inStream.seekg(0, ios::beg);
//3. inStream.seekg(0, inStream.beg);
//4. inStream.close(); inStream.open("infile.txt");
//I have tried all four of these lines and only #4 works. 
//There has got to be a more natural option than just 
//closing and reopening the file. Right?

inStream >> first >> second >> third;
outStream << "And again, the sum of the first 3 nums is " << (first+second+third) << endl;

inStream.close();
outStream.close();
return 0;
}
```

Maybe I don't understand quite how the stream works, but I've seen a few sources that said that seekg(0) should move the index back to the start of the file. Instead, this is what I get out of it.

> The sum of the first 3 nums is 8
>
> The sum of the second 3 nums is 14
>
> And again, the sum of the first 3 nums is 14

It went back, but not nearly in the way I would have hoped. Any idea why this happened? Why did my first three attempts fail?

Comment: What is `infile.txt`? Specifically, what are the numbers?

Comment: @Tushar More importantly, what is its contents in addition to the numbers.  There must be more, since you need white space to separate the numbers.  If the file ends with a `'\n'` (which it should if it is a text file), then all but the first method he uses are guaranteed by the standard (and the first will work in practice as well).

Comment: Also important is the compiler/library he's using.  C++11 defines `seekg` differently than C++03.

Comment: infile.txt:
1\n
2\n
5\n
4\n
1\n
9
Using MS Visual C++ 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bo Persson states, it *may* be because your input has
encountered end of file; it shouldn't, because in C++, a text
file is defined as being terminated by a `'\n'`, but practically
speaking, if you're working under Windows, a lot of ways of
generating a file will omit this final `'\n'`—although it
is formally required, practical considerations will mean that
you'll make sure that it works even if the final `'\n'` is
missing.  And I can't think of any other reason off hand why the
`seekg`'s wouldn't work.  `inStream.seekg( 0 )` is, of course,
undefined behavior, but in practice, it will work pretty much
everywhere.  `inStream.seekg( 0, ios::beg )` is guaranteed to
work *if* `inStream.good()`, and is, IMHO, preferable to the
first form.  (The single argument form of `seekg` is normally
only used with the results of a `tellg` as an argument.)  And of
course, it only works if the actual input source supports 
seeking: it won't work if you're reading from a keyboard or
a pipe (but presumably, `"infile.txt"` is neither).

In general, you should check the status of `inStream` after each
read, before using the results.  But if the only problem is that
the file doesn't end with `'\n'`, it's probable that the status
will be OK (`!fail()`) after the final read, even if you've
encountered end of file.  In which case, you'll need `clear()`
anyway.

Note that the above comments are valid for C++-03 and precedent.
C++11 has changed the specification of the single argument form
of `seekg`, and requires it to reset `eofbit` *before* anything
else.  (Why is this change only for the single argument form of
`seekg`, and not the two argument form?  Oversight?)

Comment: That's perfect. I forgot to include a trailing '\n', but MSVC++ did not consider this worthy of a warning. Additionally, inStream.clear() also worked. Thanks everyone for the tips.

Comment: @anthony The problem with `'\n'` in the Windows world is that there doesn't seem to be any agreement as to whether the CRLF is a separator, or a terminator.  The VC++ library treats it as a terminator, but most other programs treat it as a separator.  (If it is logically a separator, `filebuf` should generate a `'\n'` automatically when it reaches end of file, and should output nothing for the final `'\n'` that you output.  In a text file only, of course.  Practically, the only thing to do is to expect the final `'\n'` to be missing; it _will_ happen (even under Unix).

Answer (score 2):

The second input reaches end-of-file for the stream. That state sticks until you call `inStream.clear()` to clear its state (in addition to the seek).

With a C++11 compliant compiler, option 4 should also work as close and reopen will now clear the previous state. Older compilers might not do that.

Comment: In c++11, `seekg`  clears eofbit. There could be other error flags set, though.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear that he's reached end of file.  If there's any white space in the file after the six numbers, he won't have.  (And logically, since it's a text file, there should be at least a `'\n'` after the last number.)

Comment: @jrok Only the one argument form resets `eofbit`.  But the one argument form is undefined behavior if called with an integral constant.  And if the input file actually does contain 6 numbers, `eofbit` is the only possible problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
inStream.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
```

Comment: Actually, I never tried that. What's the difference between this and (0, ios::beg)?